# Horizontal alignment within an equation environment

Tags: equations, horizontal-alignment

My wish would be that within the "Equation" environment, the name for the equation would be left-aligned on the same line as the formula, but the formula would still appear centered (as if the text were not there).

Background is that "many" formula will be below each other, but only some will have text added.

Who could help me further?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikzscale}
\usepackage[justification=centering]{subcaption}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

\blindtext

\textbf{Einstein}
\begin{equation}  
E=m \cdot c^2
\end{equation}

\blindtext

\begin{equation}  
\textbf{Einstein} \quad E=m \cdot c^2
\end{equation}

\blindtext

\begin{equation}  
c^2=a^2+b^2
\end{equation}

\blindtext

\end{document}
```

EDIT:
I have attached a picture here to make my wish a little clearer.

[image: A Picture]

EDIT 2:

I have added a second example code here. With the Vorschalg of Zarko.
Unfortunately, I additionally want the equation to remain centered in the line. In the example you can see that equation (1) and equation (2) are not on top of each other. Do you have a suggestion for this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikzscale}
\usepackage[justification=centering]{subcaption}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\blindtext

\begin{flalign}
\textbf{Einstein}  &
    &  E & =m \cdot c^2 &
\end{flalign}


\begin{equation}  
E=m \cdot c^2
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}  
c^2=a^2+b^2
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}  
E=m \cdot c^2
\end{equation}

\blindtext

\end{document}
```

[image: Picture 2]

Comment: I, for example, have not understood your question.

Comment: If you use `amsmath`, the option `[leqno]` should give you the result you want.

Comment: @ Sebastiano:  Thanks for your feedback. Please see above, I edited my question a bit.

Comment: Hi barbara beeton, I understood that with "leqno" you can only set the equation number to left justified. However, I would like to have an additional text left-aligned and still set the equation number on the right side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not *really* the same, but…

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newenvironment{namedequation}[1]{%
  \begin{equation}
  \hspace{0pt}%
  \makebox[1.5em][l]{\textbf{#1}}\mathopen{\!}%
  \hspace{1000pt minus 1fill}%
}{\hspace{1000pt minus 1fill}\end{equation}}


\begin{document}

\begin{namedequation}{Einstein}
E=m \cdot c^2
\end{namedequation}

\begin{equation}  
E=m \cdot c^2
\end{equation}

\begin{namedequation}{Einstein}
E=m \cdot c^2\rlap{\smash{\vrule height 10pt depth 1.5cm}}
\end{namedequation}

\begin{equation}  
E=m \cdot c^2
\end{equation}

\setcounter{equation}{8}

\begin{namedequation}{Einstein}
E=m \cdot c^2\rlap{\smash{\vrule height10pt depth 1.5cm}}
\end{namedequation}

\begin{equation}  
E=m \cdot c^2
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The 'Edited' solution with `\flalign` (for "full line align") is close what I'm used to do in such case. The remaining problem can be improved, though not perfectly, by loading `mathtools` package (a super set of `ammsmath`) and using its `\mathrlap` macro.
MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{blindtext}
%\usepackage{amsmath}  %<< removed
\usepackage{mathtools} %>> added

\begin{document}
\blindtext
\begin{flalign}
&\mathrlap{\textbf{Einstein}} & E & =m \cdot c^2  &
\end{flalign}
to compare without \texttt{\string\mathrlap}
\begin{flalign}
&\textbf{Einstein} & E & =m \cdot c^2  &
\end{flalign}
and with \texttt{equation}
\begin{equation}  
E=m \cdot c^2
\end{equation}
\blindtext
\end{document}
```

Result :
[image]

UPDATE :
The slight extra-offset of the previous solution comes from the space occupied by the equation number. This effect can be eliminated by making it zero length by a similar strategy (`\llap`). Let's define a devoted macro :

```
\makeatletter
\NewDocumentCommand{\textequation}{smm}{%
\IfBooleanTF{#1}{%
\begin{flalign*}
&\mathrlap{\text{#2}} & #3 &
\end{flalign*}}{%
\bgroup%
\let\SAV@maketag@@@=\maketag@@@%
\renewcommand{\maketag@@@}[1]{\llap{\SAV@maketag@@@ ##1}}}%
\begin{flalign}
&\mathrlap{\text{#2}} & #3 &
\end{flalign}%
\egroup
}
\makeatother
```

[image]
that can be used with and without the *